# Cassandra Digest Mismatch Error

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I see the following message in Cassandra's debug.log frequently and sometimes before losing nodes in the cluster. Any ideas on what the message means, and how to fix the underlying issue?

```
    DEBUG [ReadRepairStage:9346] 2017-11-06 22:29:46,135  ReadCallback.java:242 - Digest mismatch:
org.apache.cassandra.service.DigestMismatchException: Mismatch for key DecoratedKey(-8713145541289520569, 00114c65616465722f6d61737465722f352e3100000364633100) (408c7e13eea38efc9429366038cbe4a3 vs 8ce8acece0966903ac590d3229099398)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.DigestResolver.compareResponses(DigestResolver.java:92) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.ReadCallback$AsyncRepairRunner.run(ReadCallback.java:233) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [cassandra-all-3.11.0.1900.jar:3.11.0.1900]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
```

Here are the details of the Cassandra cluster:

- 4 node cluster
- Each is an AWS instance of type m4.2xlarge
- Each has an io1 volume with 20000 IOPS
- All on same VPC, with 10.0.0.x private IP addresses
- DataStax Enterprise Server 5.1.5

Answer (score 2):

I think these are harmless messages from read repair noticing different data on different nodes, and probably not the cause of your node going down. See a more detailed answer this question last year: [Datastax Mismatch for Key Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765813/datastax-mismatch-for-key-issue)