# Spring boot Cassandra read timeout

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have problem with Spring Boot + cassandra web application. It started to appear with data grown, and now it's super common scenario.

All queries sometimes doesn't work, `CassandraRepository` returns `null`. And few seconds later it works again, and next few seconds it's not working again. So web application constantly returns `200` or `404` response. The same query works in `cqlsh` all time.

I'm using:

- spring-boot-starter-parent#2.1.3
- spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra#2.1.3
- Cassandra 3.11.3 (multiple clusters)

Data structure:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE data WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE data.image (
    hash text PRIMARY KEY,
    image blob
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

To configure Cassandra connection I use:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "...path...")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
        cluster.setPort(91234);
        return cluster;
    }
```

To retrive data I'm using `CassandraRepository` with `@Query(("select * from image where id = ?0"))` QueryAnnotation. Retrieved data contains image blobs.

I think that read timeout is a problem here, servers have slow HDD disks and not so powerful CPUs. But how can I overwrite this settings with spring boot starter?

I've tried to use

```
SocketOptions so = new SocketOptions();
so.setConnectTimeoutMillis(10000);
so.setReadTimeoutMillis(20000);
cluster.setSocketOptions(so);
```

with no success.

What else can I make to have stable working solution?

Comment: Have you looked inside the cassandra logs? /var/log/cassandra/system.log. Please provide your table definition

Comment: In `system.log` I can see only this one  `INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2019-03-24 13:43:52,002 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Some operations were slow, details available at debug level (debug.log)`. A lot of them.

Comment: In debug.log: `DEBUG [MessagingService-Outgoing-/127.0.0.1-Gossip] 2019-03-24 14:06:16,719 OutboundTcpConnection.java:546 - Unable to connect to /127.0.0.1
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`, `DEBUG [ReadRepairStage:7] 2019-03-24 14:06:15,660 ReadCallback.java:242 - Digest mismatch:
org.apache.cassandra.service.DigestMismatchException: Mismatch for key DecoratedKey(3663661564007893280, 6639666664656638303430373037303465303030333033666666316630663366383436613632623466653862636166303236387831383262) (d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e vs 27f09134f25234521d54dcac9cd490ee)`

Comment: Data structure added to question too.

Comment: See that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765813/datastax-mismatch-for-key-issue

Comment: Default consistency level for Cassandra in Spring is `LOCAL_ONE` -> so, if I understand this correctly, read repair should not be problem. Or I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nodetool repair` helped -> after a few days everything started to work as expected. Conclusion: too much write do database.